# Webpack module-type sourcemaps are pointing to 'undefined' file

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm building an app with multiple widgets. These widgets are fairly big in size, so they are placed in separate sub-directories within the parent directory. The file structure looks something like this:

```
./
+-- server/
|
+-- client/
|
+-- widget1/
|
+-- widget2/
|
+-- widget3/
|
+-- package.json
+-- webpack.base.config
```

Each widget is a module completely separated from the other client and widgets, and are developed on their own, with their own development servers, etc.

---

Now the problem: when setting the `webpackConfig.devtool` to anything that uses `module` (ie. `cheap-module-source-map`), the widget files do not receive the correct source-maps. Instead they receive a filename/line number that looks like: `(index):40`. (or `webpack:///:40` when mousing over) When clicking on said file in chrome, it points me to a file with these contents:

```
undefined


/** WEBPACK FOOTER **
 ** 
 **/
```

Now the incredibly weird thing about this is that even when building the client app, which brings all the widgets and the client-side code together, **only** the widget files have these messed up source-maps.

The contents of each widget is simply a bunch of `.js` and `.scss` files, with an `index.html` and `development-server.js` for development. The client side code is virtually the same, expect for the development files.

---

This is webpack-1, version 1.13.0.

My `webpack.base.config` looks like such:

```
const babelQuery = {
  es2015: require.resolve('babel-preset-es2015'),
  react: require.resolve('babel-preset-react'),
};

function createQuery(...paths) {
  return paths.map(resolvePath => `presets[]=${resolvePath}`).join(',');
}

const fullQuery = createQuery(babelQuery.es2015, babelQuery.react);

module.exports = {
  cache: true,
  context: __dirname,
  debug: true,
  devtool: '#cheap-module-source-map',

  entry: {},

  output: {},

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx'],
  },

  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: `babel-loader?cacheDirectory,${createQuery(babelQuery.es2015)}`,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.jsx$/,
        loader: `react-hot-loader!babel-loader?cacheDirectory,${fullQuery}`,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        loader: 'json-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loader: 'style-loader' +
        '!css-loader?modules&sourceMap&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]' +
        '!postcss-loader!sass-loader?outputStyle=expanded&sourceMap',
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader?name=img/[name].[ext]',
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg|woff(2)?)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?(\?[a-z0-9]+)?$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: 'style-loader!css-loader?modules&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]',
        include: /flexboxgrid/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: 'style-loader!css-loader',
        exclude: /flexboxgrid/,
      },
    ],
  },

  postcss() {
    return [autoprefixer];
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('development'),
      },
    }),
  ],
};
```

The widgets' development servers modify the base config like so: (if it matters)

```
  context: __dirname,
  entry: {
    bundle: [
      'webpack/hot/dev-server',
      'webpack-hot-middleware/client',
      './entry.jsx',
    ],
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    publicPath: `http://localhost:${PORT}/assets/`,
    filename: '[name].js',
  },
```

Comment: Did you solve it? Have the same problem...

Comment: No, I have yet to solve it. My current workaround is to avoid using `module` in my source-map configuration, (specifically using `cheap-eval-source-map` right now) but my source-maps are much worse. Transformed code can be hard to navigate.

Answer (score 0):

Try `eval-source-map` or `source-map`.

It's slower I know, but with a small cost of longer rebuilding time in dev mode it works just fine.

My loader in webpack config looks like this:

```
{
  output: {
    pathinfo: true,
    path: path.join(__dirname, "build"),
    filename: "app.js",
    publicPath: "/"
  },

  entry: [
    "webpack-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:3000",
    "webpack/hot/only-dev-server",
    "babel-polyfill",
    "whatwg-fetch",
    path.join(__dirname, "./main")
  ],

  devtool: "eval-source-map",
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        include: [
          path.join(__dirname, "src"),
          path.join(__dirname, "node_modules/localforage")
        ],
        loader: "react-hot!babel?cacheDirectory"
      },
    ]
  }

  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      "process.env": {
        "NODE_ENV": "\"development\"",
        "BASE_DIR": "\"baseDir\"",
      }
    })
  ]
}
```

and my .babelrc:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "stage-0", "react"],
  "plugins": ["transform-decorators-legacy"],
  "env": {
    "production": {
      "presets": ["react-optimize"]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, although I was aware of this solution when I wrote the question. I was hoping to get the `module` type source maps to work as they both compile fast and have decent quality. I've opted for `cheap-eval-source-map` right now as speed is more important for my workflow.